# Can not use .ToListAsync() extension method (.net 4.7)

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, entity-framework-6

Im am trying to use extension method `.ToListAsync()` but for some reason this extension method not available for me.

My set up as follows:

- Web Project (.Net 4.7) here i did include `using System.Data.Entity;`
- DataAcess Project (.Net 4.7) here I interlude `Entity Frame Work v6.2`

My Web Project does reference my DataAccess project.

Im not sure where i went wrong. Can somebody please advise?

Thank you!

Comment: In which project are you trying to use the method? Web or data access?

Comment: @DavidG Im trying to use it in my `Web` project

Comment: Does the web project reference `EntityFramework.dll`?

Comment: @DavidG No. I am referencing `DataAccess` project that is references `EntityFramework`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `ToListAsync` method is part of the [`QueryableExtensions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.queryableextensions(v=vs.113).aspx) class which is in the `System.Data.Entity` namespace and part of the `EntityFramework.dll` library. This means that you need import the namespace (i.e. `using System.Data.Entity;`) as well as reference `EntityFramework.dll`.

Note that in classic .Net Framework projects, references are not transitive. In other words, if you want to use classes from a library, you must reference it in every project. This has changed in .Net Core though.

Comment: Thank you. 
Does this mean I have to install `EntityFrameWork` in web project as well? If so, is there a way to isolate this dependency somehow?

Comment: Yes, install it there too. There's no downside to this as it's already part of your solution.

Answer (score 3):

While the `.ToListAsync()` method is made available by referencing the EntityFramework.dll and `using System.Data.Entity;`, it is only available on types that implement the `IQueryable` interface.

An example of it being used:

```
private async Task<List<Book>> GetAllBooksAsync() {

    var books = new List<Book>();
    var query = from item in books select item;
    return await query.AsQueryable().ToListAsync();
}
```

As a note, if you can't see the `ToListAsync()` method, you may be missing the `using System.Data.Entity;` in your class.

Comment: Haha it doesn't. I was typing this out while you were submitting your answer, David. You beat me to the punch. Good stuff David!

Comment: In 2023, I think that method was removed.  Using .NET 7 and there is no ToListAsync() even though I'm using System.Data.Entity.