# how to implement WHERE in asyncmethod

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

I'm trying to implement an async method using Where(). I can't find any async version of the Where method. and ToListAsync is not avaiable for IEnumerable. Should I use a different method?

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> Where(Func<TEntity, bool> predicate)
{
    var tmp = await this.DbSet.Where(predicate).ToListAsync(); //error: ToListAsync not available

    return tmp;
}
```

DbSet is of type `DbSet<TEntity>`

The project targets .NET Standard 2.0 and references Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.2.1, and I have defined "using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore".

I see in the [Doc's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions) that most of the extensions targets IQueryable<>, but I work with IEnumerable<>. could that be the problem?
But Where() returns IEnumerable.

Any ideas?

Comment: @er-mfahhgk do you know if there's something similar for ASP.NET Core?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use an Expression, not a Func.

So:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> Where(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
{
    var tmp = await this.DbSet.Where(predicate).ToListAsync();
    return tmp;
}
```

`Func<TEntity, bool>` expects an actual function, while `Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>` expects an expression tree.
The `IQueryable` builds your SQL query based on this expression tree.
By using a Func, you call the overload of Where from regular LINQ, which returns an IEnumerable.
Which doesn't have ToListAsync.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import namespace `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`.  See the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/async) for more details.

Comment: I use Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.2.1 and have "using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore"

Answer (score 0):

You have to add its namespace which included in `EntityFramework.dll`.

Please find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48372906/9465937).